# How to test similar distribution of categorical data (k=3) between 2 paired samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, categorical-data, paired-data

I'm looking for a test to compare the distributions of categorical data (3 levels: J,N,P) between 2 dependent groups (paired samples: question_1, question_2).

We have 85 participants, each one of them is asked the same 2 questions. For each question the participants can choose 1 of 3 possible answers (J,N,P). We then want to compare the distributions of the answers between the 2 questions, and test if they are equal or different.

Any ideas?

- Notice that these are paired samples, so the groups are dependant

Data example:

paricipant_id | question_1 | question_2

choice_1      |     17      | 10

choice_2      |     28      | 31

choice_3      |     40      | 39

It translates to the following distribution:

Question 1: 20%, 32.94%, 47.06% for choices 1, 2, 3 respectively
Question 2: 11.76%, 36.47%, 45.88% for choices 1, 2, 3 respectively

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, do you have 255 subjects? Each is asked one of two questions, chosen at random: 136 subjects are asked Question 1 and 119 subjects are asked Question 2. Each subject gives one of three responses to the chosen question.

If that is correct, you can use a chi-squared test of homogeneity. Results: chi-sq statistic = 32.65, DF=2, P-value very near 0.

So we reject, at any reasonable level of significance, the null hypothesis that responses have the same distribution for the two questions.

From R statistical software:

```
TBL = rbind(c(40,30,66), c(45,55,19))
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 32.647, df = 2, p-value = 8.143e-08
```

If my first paragraph is incorrect, please edit your question so the next person who seeks to answer won't make the same wrong interpretation I did. In particular, I was puzzled by your use of the word 'paired'.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I probably didn't explain myself very well, I will go ahead and edit the original question. I have 85 participants, each one is asked the same 2 questions and can choose 1 of 3 answers. I then want to compare the distribution of the choices between the 2 question, and test if it's the same or not

Comment: I also had a mistake in the original data I provided, please see it fixed now

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for me to understand the experimental setup from the description and from the sample data data presented.

But, likely, the appropriate test would be the McNemar–Bowker test ( [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65479/mcnemar-bowker-test-for-comparison-of-two-measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65479/mcnemar-bowker-test-for-comparison-of-two-measures))

But note that the rows and and the columns of the contingency table need to have the same levels.  That is, the rows might represent *Question 1* and have levels of  *J*, *N*, *P*, and the columns might represent *Question 2* and have levels of *J*, *N*, *P*.  This requires re-tabulating the data.  But if the data are in long format, it's easy to tabulate the data in this manner.  It also requires that you can identify the response to *Question 1* and *Question 2* for a given participant.